# SASS and Specificity

Tags: css, sass

I was refactoring code this afternoon and I realized something in peculiar that I was hoping someone could answer. I noticed the following...

```
&__main ul a {
....
};
```

equates too specificity (0, 0, 2) which makes sense. However....

```
 &__main &__example a {
...
}
```

equates to specificity (0, 0, 1) which doesn't make sense bc doesn't the above snippet equate to...

```
.div__main .div__example a {
...
}
```

which should be specificty (0, 1, 1)? Becasuse I tried the snippet below and I get the specificity which I'm looking for...

```
&__main .div__example a {
....
}
```

Can someone please explain to me please because I'm confused as to why the compiler wouldn't take specificity into account when using an & to refer to a parent class? Because when you break it down to regular CSS it should, no? (edited)

Comment: `equates to specificity (0, 0, 1)` says who?

Comment: I have no idea what tooling you're using to determine this - You should state that in your question.


That said, you're getting overly specific already imo with these selectors:

`.so74693627 .so74693627__main ul a` and 

`.so74693627 .so74693627__main .so74693627__example a`

Comment: I'm using VS  Code when I hover over the selectors.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug in VS Code has yet to be fixed.